# RDP slow on specific combination between laptop and network

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, remote-desktop

I have noticed the following, and just don't understand what could be causing this problem:

We always work on laptops via wifi and RDP

2. On a specific customer's wifi network, one specific laptop is horribly slow via RDP
3. When browsing normally on that customers network with the laptop, wifi is fast
4. When using another laptop to use RDP via that customers network, it also works fast
5. When using the laptop in question to use RDP via a different wifi network, it also works fast

So based on these observations I would conclude:

- The laptop is fine
- The RDP setup is fine
- The customers wifi network is fine

But unfortunately, the combination of these still poses a problem, hence my question:

### How tot troubleshoot a very slow RDP service via a specific laptop on a specific network when all individual components seem to be working fine?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest getting a hold of Wireshark and doing a capture of an RDP session.  Then you can look for things that might be slowing you down, like DNS lookups, etc.  Or, it may exonerate the network altogether and you can concentrate on the laptop.